# Beanshell not equal statement

Tags: java, beanshell

What is `if not equal` statement in beanshell ? if this is equal :

```
if ("myVarValue".equals(vars.get("MY_VARIABLE")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `!` unary `boolean` logical complement operator:

```
if (!"myVarValue".equals(vars.get("MY_VARIABLE")))
```

#### References

- [JLS 15.15.6 Logical Complement Operator `!`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.15.6)

> The type of the operand expression of the unary `!` operator must be `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs. The type of the unary logical complement expression is `boolean`.
>
> At run time, the operand is subject to unboxing conversion if necessary; the value of the unary logical complement expression is `true` if the (possibly converted) operand value is `false` and `false` if the (possibly converted) operand value is `true`.

---

Another option for testing `if (!something)` is to test `if (something == false)`.

#### Related questions

- [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. `if (b == false)` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-in)