# What's the most concise way to get the inverse of a Java boolean value?

Tags: java, boolean, inverse

If you have a boolean variable:

```
boolean myBool = true;
```

I could get the inverse of this with an if/else clause:

```
if (myBool == true)
 myBool = false;
else
 myBool = true;
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: BoltClock has the optimal answer; I'd like to note though, that "if (myBool == true)" is by itself already very chatty; "if (myBool)" does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @phisch: `if ((!myBool != true || false) && (!(myBool != false || true) == false))`

Comment: myBool = (myBool) ? false : true;  (because I just can't resist the opportunity to use the ternary form even if this isn't - the most - concise)

Comment: He forgot the braces. if(myBool == true) { myBool = false; } ... :-)

Comment: `if (myBool == true)`, eek. Related: [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-in)

Comment: by the way, the object oriented version xD `myBool = Boolean.FALSE.equals(myBool);`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Just assign using the logical NOT operator `!` like you tend to do in your condition statements (`if`, `for`, `while`...). You're working with a boolean value already, so it'll flip `true` to `false` (and vice versa):

```
myBool = !myBool;
```

Comment: This is indeed more concise.  But I would like to point out that the answer from `bvdb` deals with properly handling `Boolean`

Answer (score 46):

An even cooler way (that is more concise than `myBool = !myBool` for variable names longer than 4 characters if you want to *set* the variable):

```
myBool ^= true;
```

And by the way, don't use `if (something == true)`, it's simpler if you just do `if (something)` (the same with comparing with false, use the negation operator).

Comment: Heck yeah XOR! +1

Comment: Those are the little things that make the endless hours of programming funnier xD

Comment: I was hoping to find a concise syntax that my coworkers will understand intuitively without needing to ask a question on StackOverflow to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: You are not thinking in positive! Think about the enlightenment they will get after browsing SO for a while trying to understand what you were doing!!! :-p

Comment: You're right. Let's see what they think of our efforts to enlighten them.

Comment: They will be delighted, I can tell you that! :-D

Comment: how about `myBool = (myBool == false);`?

Comment: @faq: You're completely missing the point! The goal of programming isn't to write programs that others can understand. It's to write programs that are so sophisticated that anyone reading it is instantly impressed with how smart you must have been to be able to write this. :)

Comment: @Jay or as a friend of mine would say: If it was hard to write, it should be hard to read! XD

Comment: What are the benefits of the bitwise XOR method? (Other than coolness).

Comment: no benefits, just for bugging your fellows... (and it's not bitwise, it's a boolean operator since it's applied on boolean operands!)

Comment: This solution is neat. To say `myBool = !myBool` allows you to only exactly flip the boolean value. But, `myBool ^= true` can be generalised as `myBool ^= reverse` which allows you to selectively invert its boolean value.

Answer (score 19):

For a `boolean` it's pretty easy, a `Boolean` is a little bit more challenging.

- A `boolean` only has 2 possible states:
  `true`and `false`.
- A `Boolean` on the other hand, has 3: `Boolean.TRUE`,
  `Boolean.FALSE` or `null`.

Assuming that you are just dealing with a `boolean` (which is a primitive type) then the easiest thing to do is:

```
boolean someValue = true; // or false
boolean negative = !someValue;
```

However, if you want to invert a `Boolean` (which is an object), you have to watch out for the `null` value, or you may end up with a `NullPointerException`.

```
Boolean someValue = null;
Boolean negativeObj = !someValue.booleanValue(); --> throws NullPointerException.
```

Assuming that this value is never null, and that your company or organization has no code-rules against auto-(un)boxing. You can actually just write it in one line.

```
Boolean someValue = Boolean.TRUE; // or Boolean.FALSE
Boolean negativeObj = !someValue;
```

However if you do want to take care of the `null` values as well. Then there are several interpretations.

```
boolean negative = !Boolean.TRUE.equals(someValue); //--> this assumes that the inverse of NULL should be TRUE.

// if you want to convert it back to a Boolean object, then add the following.
Boolean negativeObj = Boolean.valueOf(negative);
```

On the other hand, if you want `null` to stay `null` after inversion, then you may want to consider using the `apache commons` class `BooleanUtils`([see javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html))

```
Boolean someValue = null; // or Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE;
Boolean negativeObj = BooleanUtils.negate(someValue);
```

Some prefer to just write it all out, to avoid having the apache dependency.

```
Boolean someValue = null; // or Boolean.TRUE or Boolean.FALSE;
Boolean negative = (someValue == null)? null : Boolean.valueOf(!someValue.booleanValue());
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I feel the accepted answer is indeed more concise. BUT I feel your answer is more complete!  Thank you for covering `boolean` AND `Boolean`

Comment: I gave you thumb up, but just to put a note on Boolean negation - the way you did it causes 'The expression of type Boolean is unboxed into boolean'

Comment: @horvoje some code inspections prefer auto-(un)boxing, others forbid it. You can disable/enable the inspections in the configuration of your IDE, depending on your personal preference. Personally, I would avoid auto-unboxing until you really understand the implications for null-values.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise way is to not invert the boolean, and just use !myBool later on in the code when you want to check the opposite condition.

Comment: you are right, but sometimes you need to do it if it's a flag that actually changes

Answer (score -3):

```
myBool = myBool ? false : true;
```

Comment: copied from the comments to the question?

Comment: Is there no difference between both?