# What is better java syntax: if (isSomething() == false) { or if (!isSomething()) {

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style

If you look at

```
if (!x) {
if (x == false) {
```

It looks like !x is better, but

```
if (!isSomething()) {
if (isSomething() == false) {
```

you can easily oversee the !

What to do? Is there a recommendation?

Comment: Some of the answers in this question address this issue. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hidden third option is to name your variables and methods properly.

Instead of

```
if (!isDisabled()) {
    ...
}
```

use

```
if (isEnabled()) {
    ...
}
```

or if you want to check for the negative:

```
boolean disabled = !isEnabled();
if (disabled) {
    ...
}
```

or add both methods:

```
boolean isDisabled() {
    return !isEnabled();
}
```

Edit: I found this question: [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-in)

Comment: +1 yep, I think if you have a function is better to make it that you check if the return value is true more then if it's not false, like: if(isEnabled()){}

Answer (score 7):

I would stick with the notation `if (!isSomething()) {`. If you or others find it hard to read you can always add a little whitespace around the '!' in order to make it stand out:

`if ( ! isSomething()) {` or `if ( !isSomething()) {`

Furthermore, multiple conditional statements can become overwhelming with the following notation

`if (isSomething() == false && isSomethingElse() == false && ..)`,

whereas its alternative is short and succinct. After a while it becomes natural to read the '!' along with the statements as "not isSomething() and not isSomethingElse()".

Comment: +1 for the spaces around "!" trick, I never think about doing this, but it can be useful :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any recommendation that everyone would follow.

Do it your way, personnally, I would choose the `if (!isSomething())` style :)

Especially since I already chose the `if (!x)` style.

Comment: +1 for the consistency argument. Com'on, LaGrandMere, almost 1000 ;)

Comment: @VonC : thanks mate, it's done, I got my first 1000 points :)

Comment: yes, excellent! Now if you can just lose the "Hi!" ;) and you will have a better fit with the spirit of this Q&A site (just about answers)

Comment: @VonC : Haha, I'm a desperate chatter, I think :D

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( !isSomething() ) {
```

would be the best in my opinion. This way you're keeping the character count down, your code is readable and that `!` does stick out at the beginning, so just by skimming through code, others can see its intention.