# another homework question error unexpected type required:variable found:value

Tags: java

I have another error,     unexpected type  required:variable found:value       and I can't figure out why.  The code is as follows:

```
public class ISBNText extends JTextField
{  
    protected static final int ISBN_NUM=10;
    protected static String bookNum;
    protected JTextField  bookText; 
    protected String valid;
    public ISBNText() 
    {
        super(20);
    }   

    public String getISBN()
    {           
        bookNum = getText();
        return bookNum;
    }

    private String validateISBN(String bookNum)throws ISBNException
    {
        boolean check=false;
        bookNum.replaceAll("-","");
        if (bookNum.length()!=ISBN_NUM)
            throw new ISBNException ("ISBN "+ bookNum + " must be 10 characters");
        for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length()-1;i++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(bookNum.charAt(i)))
                check=true;
        }  
        if (bookNum.charAt(9)=='X') check=true;
        if (Character.isDigit(bookNum.charAt(9))) check=true;
        if (check=false) throw new ISBNException ("ISBN " + bookNum + " must contain all digits" + 
                "or 'X' in the last position");
        if (checkDigit(bookNum)=false)      //////////COMPILER   ERROR    HERE////////
            throw new ISBNException ("ISBN " + bookNum + " is invalid.\n" + 
                "ISBN " + bookNum + " should be " + validnum);
        if (check=true) return bookNum;
    }                             

    public boolean checkDigit (String bookNum)
    {
        boolean status;
        double total=0.0;
        char[] check   = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X};
        int[] checkNums= {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length;i++)
        {
            check(i)=bookNum[i];
            total+=check[i]*checkNums[i];
        }    
        if ((checkNums[9] % 11)==check[9])
            status = true;
        else 
            status=false;
    }
}
```

This program is being used to check the validity of an ISBN number entered by a user.  I don't understand why it says it finds value and it expects a variable, as bookNum is a variable.  I have no doubt that this is due to my limited knowledge.  Hoping you guys can help me out one more time.

Comment: I suspect ISBN_NUM should have a lowercase leading character. But what line is the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkDigit(bookNum)=false` should be     !checkDigit(bookNum)

Same thing for `if (check=false)` which should be if (!check)
Another with if (check=true)

Also,

```
for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length;i++)
{
    check(i)=bookNum[i];
    total+=check[i]*checkNums[i];
}
```

Should be :

```
for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length();i++)
{
    (something, but definitely not a function result)=bookNum.charAt(i);
    total+=check[i]*checkNums[i];
}
```

Plus,

```
char[] check   = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X}; // X won't compile
```

Plus,

checkDigit has no return.

Plus,

validnum is not declared

Comment: i got the X, I put it in 'ticks' and now it compiles. How would I get bookNum.getCharAt(i);? Yeah, the return for checkDigit is in now, and I haven't got to validNum.   Work in progress

Comment: It was charAt(i), my mistake. As bookNum isn't a array, I guess that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

This assignment (which doesn't make sense)

```
if (checkDigit(bookNum)=false)
```

should rather have been an equation

```
if (checkDigit(bookNum)==false)
```

or, [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-in), just an expression

```
if (!checkDigit(bookNum))
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - equality operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)
- [Java tutorial - if statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: works like a charm, should have realized.  Always miss those assignment operators vs check operators.  Darn.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `charAt`, not the array index notation on the `bookNum` variable in the `checkDigit` method.  Strings are not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==`, not `=`. The former checks for equality, the latter is an assignment operator. Alternatively, you could just do `if (!checkDigit(bookNum))`, rather than an explicit comparison to `false`.