# Unable to add window -- token is your activity running

Tags: android

I have an android project, all source code haven't error but sometimes it give me a force close.

here is my code :

timecompletedialog.java

```
public class TimeCompleteDialog implements OnClickListener {

    private Activity act;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    /**UI Components*/
    private Dialog dialog;
    private TextView txt_msg;

    private ImageButton btn_cancal;

    public TimeCompleteDialog(Activity a) {
        this.act=a;

        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(act);
        dialog=new Dialog(a);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
    /**Attaching the dialog to custom views*/
    private  void buildDialog(){        
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_complete_dialog,null,false);
        dialog.setContentView(v);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.findDialogViews(v);
    }

    public void showDialog(){
        this.buildDialog();
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    /**Find the ids of the custom views components*/
    private  void findDialogViews(View view){
        txt_msg=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_up);
        btn_cancal=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_time_cancel);

        btn_cancal.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**Changing the state of the views*/
        this.renderViews();

    }

    private void renderViews() {
        txt_msg.setText("Sorry Time is up.\nTry Harder Next Time");
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_time_cancel:
            this.dialog.dismiss();
            act.finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        //Closing the dialog

    }
}
```

in this code it have no error. but i don't know what's wrong.

and here is my quizactivity

```
public class QuizActivity extends BaseFragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,AnswerListener,
                                    OnTimeCompleteListener{

    private TextView questionTextView,timer_text,score_text;
    private ImageButton option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    public static int LEVEL=0,timer=0;
    private Handler handler=new Handler();
    private OnTimeCompleteListener timeComplete=(OnTimeCompleteListener)this;
    private Runnable timerThread=new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(timer>0){
                //Time is running 
                timer--;
                timer_text.setText("Time : "+timer);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }else{
                timeComplete.onTimeFinish();

            }

        }
    };

    private int QUESTION_COUNTER=1;
    private int SCORE_COUNTER=0;
    public static int QUESTION_LIMIT;
    private CurrentQuestion currentQuestion ;
    UtilityFile utility;

    private static final String TEST_DEVICE_ID = "TES_EMULATOR";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_activity_layout);

        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView5);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice(TEST_DEVICE_ID).build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



        layout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.subject_animate1);
        score_text=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.score);
        timer_text=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.time);
        score_text.setText("Score : "+"0/"+QUESTION_LIMIT);


        questionTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
        option_1 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.quiz_level_option_1);
        option_2 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.quiz_level_option_2);
        option_3 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.quiz_level_option_3);
        option_4 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.quiz_level_option_4);


        option_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        option_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        option_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        option_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        /**Utility for formating of the question*/
        utility=new UtilityFile();
        refreshQuestion();
        handler.postDelayed(timerThread, 10);
        Log.i("questionset", ""+QuizQuestionHandler.lev1.size());



    }


    public void refreshQuestion(){
        List<Integer> randomOptionOrdering=new ArrayList<Integer>();        
        currentQuestion = utility
                .setCurrentQuestionSet(QuizQuestionHandler.lev1);

        ImageButton buttons[]={option_1,option_2,option_3,option_4};
        int answerIndex=utility.randInt(0, 3);  
        Log.i("answertag",""+answerIndex);
        //Right Answer
        buttons[answerIndex].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                currentQuestion.getCurrentSet().getAnsImage()));
        buttons[answerIndex].setTag((Object)currentQuestion.getCurrentSet().getId());
        questionTextView.setText(""
                + currentQuestion.getCurrentSet().getQuestion());       
        //Options

        buttons[randomOrder(randomOptionOrdering, answerIndex)].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                currentQuestion.getOption_1().getAnsImage()));
        buttons[randomOrder(randomOptionOrdering, answerIndex)].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                currentQuestion.getOption_2().getAnsImage()));
        buttons[randomOrder(randomOptionOrdering, answerIndex)].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                currentQuestion.getOption_3().getAnsImage()));

    }

    public int randomOrder(List<Integer> rand,int currentAnswerIndex){
        while(true){
            int index = new UtilityFile().randInt(0,3);
            if(index!=currentAnswerIndex){
                if (!isInserted(rand, index)) {
                    rand.add(index);
                    Log.i("return",""+index);
                    return index;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    public  boolean isInserted(List<Integer> inserted,int currentIndex){
        for(Integer inte:inserted){
            if(inte==currentIndex){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        disableOptionButton();
        AnswerFinder finder=null;
        switch (v.getId()) {        
        case R.id.quiz_level_option_1:
             finder=new AnswerFinder(option_1,currentQuestion , this);
             finder.getAnswer();
            break;
        case R.id.quiz_level_option_2:
             finder=new AnswerFinder(option_2,currentQuestion , this);
             finder.getAnswer();
            break;
        case R.id.quiz_level_option_3:
             finder=new AnswerFinder(option_3,currentQuestion , this);
             finder.getAnswer();
            break;
        case R.id.quiz_level_option_4:
             finder=new AnswerFinder(option_4,currentQuestion , this);
             finder.getAnswer();
            break;      
        default:
            break;
        }       
    }
    private void disableOptionButton(){
    option_1.setClickable(false);
    option_2.setClickable(false);
    option_3.setClickable(false);
    option_4.setClickable(false);   
    }
    private void enableOptionButton(){
        option_1.setClickable(true);
        option_2.setClickable(true);
        option_3.setClickable(true);
        option_4.setClickable(true);
    }
    public void animateNext(){
        Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.right_to_left);
        layout.startAnimation(anim);
        anim.setDuration(200);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
                stopTimer();

            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                /**Handling Animation Delays and Render Other Animations
                 * */
                Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.left_to_right);
                anim.setDuration(200);
                refreshQuestion();
                layout.startAnimation(anim);
                startTimer();
            }
        });
    }


    public void startTimer(){
        handler.postDelayed(timerThread, 100);
    }
    public void stopTimer(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(timerThread);
    }
    /**For getting the call of right and wrong answer*/
    @Override
    public void onAnswerClick(boolean answer) {     
        /**Check for the question overflow*/
        if(QUESTION_COUNTER<QUESTION_LIMIT){
            if(answer){
                SCORE_COUNTER++;
                AnswerHandler.rightAnswerHandler(score_text,this,SCORE_COUNTER,QUESTION_LIMIT);
            }else{
                //AnswerHandler.wrongAnswerHandler(this);
            }
            animateNext();
            QUESTION_COUNTER++;
        }else{
            /**Incrementing the final score*/           
            SCORE_COUNTER++;
            AnswerHandler.finalAnswerPlayer(this);
            this.gameCompleted();
        }
        enableOptionButton();
    }

    public void gameCompleted(){
        GameCompleteDialog dialog=new GameCompleteDialog(QuizActivity.this,SCORE_COUNTER);
        dialog.buildDialog();
        dialog.showDialog();            
        handler.removeCallbacks(timerThread);
    }
    public void onTimeFinish() {
        TimeCompleteDialog dialog=new TimeCompleteDialog(this);
        dialog.showDialog();
        AnswerHandler.vibrate(this);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
        {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

here is my logcat:

```
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180): Process: com.sendquiz.guessanimalsquiz, PID: 2180
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@b2282c30 is not valid; is your activity running?
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:532)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at com.sendquiz.javafile.TimeCompleteDialog.showDialog(TimeCompleteDialog.java:46)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at com.sendquiz.guessanimalsquiz.QuizActivity.onTimeFinish(QuizActivity.java:254)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at com.sendquiz.guessanimalsquiz.QuizActivity$1.run(QuizActivity.java:53)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-28 02:56:58.303: E/AndroidRuntime(2180):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can you give me where's the error?

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: is in showDialog(TimeCompleteDialog.java:46)

Comment: updated question sir @ThomasR.

Comment: @Blackbelt i got it but i don't know wha'ts wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529504/unable-to-add-window-token-android-os-binderproxy-is-not-valid-is-your-activ)

Answer (score 6):

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@b2282c30 is not valid; is your activity
>   running?

This usually happens when you try to show a dialog after you call finish() on the current Activity. In your code this happens twice. In your `TimeCompleteDialog` and `onKeyDown`. What could happen is that you call finish() on your Activity, and you forget to clean the Runnable's queue. When  `timeComplete.onTimeFinish();` is called, in this case, you will experiencing this kind of crash. The first action I'd take, if I were in you, is to clean the handler's queue, when the Activity is paused. The second thing would be to check the Activity's `isRunning` flag, before showing the popup.

E.g.

```
 if (!isFinishing()) {
   // show popup
 }
```

Comment: doing this, just avoids the exception. But, the dialog.show doesn't execute, the only thing that is required :/

Comment: How would you show a pop-up if the context of the activity you are going to use to show it is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes that passed context/activity is not active context/activity..
You should pass Current activity or context

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this in my application by forcing the code to show a dialog after I had navigated to another activity (while this activity was in the background).

The fix was adding the following check before showing the dialog:

```
    if (activity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return !activity.isDestroyed() && !activity.isFinishing();
    }
```