# Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException Unable to add window -- token is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, dialog, xiaomi

I know this question is discussed several time but believe me i never got any answer working.
In my Main Activity i have used few Dialog to inform user about some operations but i get this specific error mostly (specifically 96%) on Xiaomi devices.
`

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@f839de9 is not valid; is your activity running?
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:697)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:347)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow (Toast.java:463)
android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage (Toast.java:346)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6377)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:904)
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:794)

`I covered each Dialog Show method like`

```
if (!MainActivityNew.this.isFinishing())
dialogDownload.show();
```

`
But still i am getting this error in release mode mostly on **Xiaomi** Devices
With Android Version 7,  Please help me i stuck on this problem from past one month.

Here is some data from firebase Crashlytics

Devices
100% Xiaomi
Operating systems
100% Android 7
Device states
4% background

Comment: see this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529504/unable-to-add-window-token-android-os-binderproxy-is-not-valid-is-your-activ

Comment: thanks Rajshree, but i have already mentioned i have used isFinishing() method as stated in above answer.

Comment: From where you are firing the showToast method? is it from Actiivty or AsyncTask or any other background thread?

Comment: It is from Main UI Thread

Comment: @SantoshPatange have you managed to handle it? I have a similar problem but for Motorola E4 and Android 7.1.1

Comment: Actually, this is Toast Notification error based on stacktrace

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This problem is not because of Dialog but with Toast. Mainly this Toast issue is in android 7.1 version where the context become null. There is a solution created by this gentleman [Solution](https://github.com/drakeet/ToastCompat) . I have tested and this is working very well. You can try this.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 25) {
                ToastCompat.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setBadTokenListener(toast -> {
                            Log.e("failed toast", message);
                        }).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue in android 7.1 .. in my case it is popupwindow. i am trying to display spinner as dropdown inside popupwindow. which causes crash on android 7.1 only. spinner as dialog is working fine. but i need dropdown. can anyone help me out please.

Comment: Hello @AlpeshGujarati - identical problem here: a Spinner inside a PopupWindow crashes, actually not only on Android 7.1, but on 7.1 and everything below (I've tested API versions 23,24,25 --> all crash, everything >=26 works fine)
No solution yet...

Comment: Actually 
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
helps!

Answer (score -3):

Use Asynctask or Handler
like:

```
Use private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
switch (message.what) {
  case DISPLAY_DLG:
    if (!isFinishing()) {
    dialogDownload.show();
    }
    break;
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: Like author stated - he checks whether activity isFinishing right now