# My app is crach android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: java, android

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@ec2d125 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

im use service in background, show notification

Comment: Add error log and code here.

Comment: well, is your activity running? This usually happens when you try to display a dialog or something after the activity has already finished. You would need to add more details for us to diagnose your problem accurately though.

Comment: app is work fine, some time i have this error, im use AsyncTask in background service

Comment: If your app is crashing then evidently it is not "working fine". Like I said, if you are using services or asynctask, you should check and see if the activity is finishing or finished before interacting with it.

Comment: I want to display the entire code but when I edit the question the error message appears
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: @ibrahim Check the context while you are creating.Change Context test once.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to help you out because we need more information
But as Steven said this usually happens when you are showing the dialog for a context that no longer exists, like "show dialog" after an async operation and during that operation the original activity is destroyed.

Take a look at this [Unable to add window — token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509848/9233991)