# Firebase stacktrace does not show where in the code the problem is occuring

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

Consider below crash in Firebase:

Unable to add window token android.os.BinderProxy is not valid; is your activity running?
[image]

This crash occurs in `ViewRootImpl.java`. **However, Firebase doesn't reference a part in my own code. How do I know where in my code this is happening?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509848/8109202

Comment: Hello @EzraLazuardy I understand the problem, however the question is about where in the code it is happening since I only have the Firebase crash with no reference to my own source code.

Comment: @JimClermonts
do this in on pause() method dialog.cancel();
in every screen (Activity, Fragment, etc), And you can test this case using Developer mode => don't keep activity.

enable don't keep activity feature in developer mode and open your app and change screen while dialog is open or press home button while dialog is showing you get same crash:)

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely happening because you are trying to show a dialog after execution of a background thread, while the Activity is being destroyed.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough, I've changed it: Firebase stacktrace does not show where in the code the problem is occuring

Answer (score -1):

do this in on pause() method dialog.cancel();

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough, I've changed it: Firebase stacktrace does not show where in the code the problem is occuring

Comment: @JimClermonts but in every screen for dialog do this u may never get that type of crash i resolved using this on my same problem bro

Comment: This is a huge code base. Adding this check everywhere is a cumbersome process. I was hoping there was a better solution. But I think there isn't :(.

Answer (score -1):

before closing the dialog check below condition -

```
if(!isActivityFinishing()){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough, I've changed it: Firebase stacktrace does not show where in the code the problem is occuring

Comment: according to stack trace you might be displaying or dismissing the dialog when activity is finished  thats why stack trace showing "is your activity running?" so need to check the condition isActivityFinishing before showing or displaying the dialog.

Comment: This is a huge code base. Adding this check everywhere is a cumbersome process. I was hoping there was a better solution. Find the exact line of code where this is happening.