# Using if (!bool) vs if (bool == false) in C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

Is there any sort of style consensus on the following two coding styles? I'm more curious if this is the sort of thing where one is generally preferred in good code in C#, or if this the sort of thing that gets decided when picking a style for a coding project.

Style 1: Using the ! sign to indicate a not in a conditional

```
if (!myBool)
{
  //Do Stuff...
}
```

Style 2: Using == false to indicate a check for falsehood in a conditional

```
if (myBool == false)
{
  //Do Stuff...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I personally prefer `if (!expr)` -- be consistent.

Comment: I prefer: `if (!!!!!!!!!!!!!myBool) { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: This has been asked in various ways across SO such as: [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-in).

Comment: We also have `if (myBool is false)` as well now. the idiom in C# is `if (!myBool)` but personally I quite like the `is false`. your eye is less likely to miss the `!`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The normal convention is

```
if (!myBool)
```

The one place where I don't go this route is with nullable booleans. In that case I will do

```
if (myBool == true)
{

}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if (myBool.HasValue && myBool.Value)
```

Comment: for Nul,able<bool> you can use an extesion method provided by the framework varaible.GetValueOrDefault() aswell

Comment: Disagree - For coding readability == true/false is clearer than empty/!

Comment: I like this style of nullable bool check, but others want to do:  (myBool ?? false) and they say this is the default value to use for null, but i personally think that is harder to read/understand.  Though, they came back and said what happens if null ends up == true someday, which is weird since null == null is false anyway. :)

Comment: Can you read the ! correctly ALL the time, EVERY time, without the glasses on, in a case like this: "if (!littering) { Litter(); }" => As an ageing dev I prefer "if (littering == false) { Litter(); }"

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any language for which the latter is preferred. Use the former.

### Warning!

#### There's a *reason* for this!

This indeed does what you expect, in most languages:

```
if (x == false)
    ...
```

But in e.g. C++, because `true` is just a synonym for 1 (so `2` isn't true or false), this **doesn't work**:

```
if (x != true)
    ...
```

although it's fine in C#.

In fact, it can also get tricky in .NET -- you *can* trick a boolean to take an integer value, and mess it up with bitwise arithmetic (e.g. `a & b` can be false when `a` is 1 and `b` is 2, even though both are "true").

In general, just use the former instead of worrying about boolean literals.

Comment: In languages with type coercion, you would probably want to use ===

Comment: .... Provided that you want to rely on type coercion for the specific conditional

Comment: @SkyKelsey: Might as well just say "in Javascript" :P.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!myBool)
{
  // Do Stuff here...
}
```

This is the preferred version, as since you already have a `bool` variable that contains a `true` or `false`, there is no reason to do an additional evaluation in the `if` statement.

---

### Update

Based on what aquinas has stated, this format is good to use unless you do have a nullable boolean (ex: `bool? myBool`).  If this is the case, use the former:

```
bool? myBool
if (myBool == false)
{
  // Do stuff here...
}
```