# if (boolean == false) vs. if (!boolean)

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i)

In [this NotePadProvider sample code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.4_r1/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.java#NotePadProvider.insert%28android.net.Uri,android.content.ContentValues%29), I noticed that the author chose the form:

```
    if (values.containsKey(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE) == false) {
        values.put(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE, now);
    }
```

Over:

```
    if (!values.containsKey(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE)) {
        values.put(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE, now);
    }
```

Is there any advantage in the first form over the more logical one?

Comment: It's more readable.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth Really? I would think the opposite...

Comment: Related: [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i)

Comment: In the first example you see at first glance that the expected outcome should be false. In the latter example you can only guess what is expected. Also it is easy to miss the exclamation mark.

Comment: `if (b==false)` is more verbose and harder to read. If you want to make it even more verbose, you could use `if (b == false == true == true)` (borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110)

Comment: how about `if(b != true)` to complete things. Coming from a C-Background I prefer the verbose version for clarity, however (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize that away) the verbose appoach creates more processing: `Read valaue one` `read value two` `compare` `proceed according to output` as opposed to `read value` `proceed according to value`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Apart from "readability", no. They're functionally equivalent.

<sub>("Readability" is in quotes because I hate `== false` and find `!` much more readable. But others don't.)</sub>

Comment: I think it even goes beyond the readability argument. ! (the bang operator) was created for this purpose. You should use it because it helps you write these statements in a succinct manner. You CAN write code using a more limited range of operators but your code will suck from a readability standpoint and won't be following conventions everyone uses.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly READABILITY. When reading others code, it is much more intuitive to read as **NOT CONTAINS KEY** `!values.containsKey(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE)` instead of reading **CONTAINS KEY IS FALSE** `(values.containsKey(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE) == false)`.

Comment: this is 100% preference

Answer (score 6):

This is a style choice.  It does not impact the performance of the code in the least, it just makes it more verbose for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

**-** Here its more about the `coding style` than being the **functionality**....

**-** The **1st option is very clear**, but then the **2nd one is quite elegant**... no offense, its just my view..

Answer (score 4):

No. I don't see any advantage. Second one is more straitforward.

btw: Second style is found in every corners of JDK source.

Answer (score 3):

Note: With ConcurrentMap you can use the more efficient

```
values.putIfAbsent(NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE, now);
```

I prefer the less verbose solution and avoid methods like IsTrue or IsFalse or their like.

Comment: Excellent. I love this. Since [ConcurrentMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) isn't derived from [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) and there isn't a direct connection between the two, do you have any suggestions to convert the passed `ContentValues` parameter to a `ConcurrentMap`? Oh wait, `ConcurrentMap` is an **interface**! Let me check this, I never came across `ConcurrentMap` before.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't even extend Map and I am not sure its thread safe. You could write a `putIfAbsent(ContentValues, NoteColumns.CREATED_DATE, now)` method. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first form, when used with an API that returns `Boolean` and compared against Boolean.FALSE, will never throw a `NullPointerException`.

The second form, when used with the `java.util.Map` interface, also, will never throw a `NullPointerException` because it returns a `boolean` and not a `Boolean`.

If you aren't concerned about consistent coding idioms, then you can pick the one you like, and in this concrete case it really doesn't matter. If you *do* care about consistent coding, then consider what you want to do when you check a `Boolean` that may be `NULL`.

Comment: This could be a truly enlightening answer, if I only understood where you see a `Boolean`. All I see there is a `boolean`. Please explain.

Comment: "In this concrete case it really doesn't matter." As you rightly point out, there is no Boolean shown above. My concern was for future code which might return to you a Boolean type and might be null. If you believe this will, "never happen," then this answer isn't very useful.