# Don't see why this loop does not get reached

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Because of many boolean checks i am a little confused, let me introduce me to my next code.

```
        } else {
        //check whether the player starts again. the first time we lose the player
        //will definitely get into this loop
        if(!startAgain){
            // we only do this to set a timer, we don't want to start a new game so we set this
            // to false
            newgame = false;
            startAgain = true;
            deadTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        deadTimepassed = (System.nanoTime() - deadTime)/1000000;
        if((deadTimepassed < 2000) && (newgame = false)){
            newGame();
        }
    }
}
```

This else statement can be seen as the first time a player gets hit by an enemy missile. To make an explosion-animation. I need te screen to freeze for 2 seconds and then start the game over again. I don't see why the second if statement is never reached. Here are my ontouch methods and my new game method:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    //What happens when the player touches the screen!

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        // Boolean check for when player is playing, if he isn't the chopper does nothing.
        // we see that the chopper only hangs still if all these booleans are true!
        if ((!player.isPlaying()) && (newgame = true) && (startAgain = true)) {
            player.setPlaying(true);

        } if(player.isPlaying()) {
            player.setUp(true);
            startAgain = false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        player.setUp(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

    public void newGame(){
    newgame = true;
    missles.clear();
    if(player.getScore()>best) {
        best = player.getScore();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveBest.edit();
        editor.putInt("new best",best);
        editor.commit();
    }
    player.resetScore();
    player.setY(HEIGHT/2);
}
```

As one can see, the new game just resets the players position, the only thing i want to do is just freeze the screen for 2 seconds before that happens, this is supposed to happen in the second if statement but it never get reached...

Any suggestions?

ps: deadTimepassed is introduced as 'private long' just beneath the public class method.

Comment: `newgame = false` is an assignment. It should be `!newgame`.

Comment: could i also use newgame == false (just out of curiousity so i understand why this fails)

Comment: @KeesTil yes you can

Comment: @KeesTil `=` is assignment `==` is comparison.

Comment: You can but **it's not recommended** when using booleans.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, can you explain why it is not recommended?

Comment: @KeesTil there is nothing wrong with doing it either way it is entirely a matter of preference.  Efficiency wise there is no difference. The only thing people would argue is readability...

Comment: @KeesTil some people would say `newgame == true` is more readable than `(newgame)` it is completely a matter of preference. Either way is correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831881/if-boolean-false-vs-if-boolean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i

Answer (score 0):

For freeze your `Thread` (so, the program will be freeze, also your screen) during 2 seconds you can use `Thread.sleep()` function:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You have to put it inside a `try-catch` block because it can gives to you an `InterruptedException`.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: This is not the best way to stop an animation. This freezes all the application (or at least the current thread when it's executed).

Comment: i thought of this, the problem with this method is that i can't play an animation during that freezed state. Thanks for the help though i appreciate it :)