# Whats the difference in checking for falsy / truthy values in different ways?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When working in JavaScript / Typescript, often times occur when i need to check a length exists or if a value is true or false.

The main question is, is there any difference in performance or behaviour between checking as follows...

```
const data = ['hello', 'good', 'day'];
(data.length) // true 
(data.length > 0) // also true
```

much like

```
const booleanValue = false;
(!booleanValue) // true 
(booleanValue === false)  //also true
```

is there a best way to do this or does it all boil down to readability.

Comment: Readability; the difference is negligible. If you need to optimise at this level, profiling beats assumptions, always (and what's fastest changes with engine type and version, as they too get optimised,)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true

Comment: *When you have a boolean value*, `!value` means exactly the same thing as `value === false` in JavaScript, so this applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831881/if-boolean-false-vs-if-boolean/11831904#11831904

Comment: Similarly, *when you have an array* and are *also using its length in a boolean context*, `value.length` and `value.length > 0` mean the same thing. But it’s easy to return the wrong type of value, e.g. if you write expressions like `data.length && data[0]` – that entire `&&` expression evaluates to `0` when the array is empty, not `false`. Better to be explicit with the types of your expressions IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences depending on what you want to achieve ...

**for example:**

```
0 == false // true
0 === false // false
undefined == null // true
undefined === null // false
...
```

Here is a game that will help you understand what are the Boolean relationships in JS:
[Pedagogical-Game](https://slikts.github.io/js-equality-game/)