# Idiomatic way of treating Option[Boolean]

Tags: scala

In my Scala program, I am receiving some JSON.

One of the fields is an optional Boolean. If the field is missing, or if its value is false, I would like to return `None`. If its value is true, I would like to return `Some(true)`.

SInce this is equivalent to converting `Some(false)` into `None`, I have defined the following function:

`def boolmap(ob: Option[Boolean]) = if(ob == Some(false)) None else ob`

It works, but it doesn't seem to be very idiomatic. Is there anything more elegant?

Comment: Since you are reducing a triadic condition to a dual condition, IMO idiomatic would be to produce a plain boolean (`getOrElse(false)`) and drop the `Option`

Comment: @0__ The thing is having the Option is quite handy for some processing I have to do later on.

Comment: Could you not use `ob.isDefined` to get the underlying boolean value?

Comment: @JasonD But would that return `None` for `Some(false)`?

Comment: It would, I see your point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is `ob.filter(identity)`.  I'm not sure whether that's clearer, but it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks! I have also found `for(x <- ob if x) yield x`

Comment: @Eduardo - Indeed.  There's also `ob.filterNot(! _)`, `ob.find(identity)`, `ob.collect{ case true => true }`, and various others.  You can also write `x=>x` in place of `identity`.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with others that you might as well just return `true` or `false` since you aren't differentiating between the attribute not being there at all, being `null` or being `false`.

If you just returned `Boolean` you could do it this way:

```
scala> Some(true) exists { _ == true }
res0: true

scala> Some(false) exists { _ == true }
res1: Boolean = false

scala> None exists { _ == true }
res2: Boolean = false
```

If you insist on returning `Option[Boolean]` a pattern match would be more idiomatic:

```
ob match { 
  case Some(true) => Some(true) 
  case _          => None 
}
```

You could also use `collect` but in this case it would look IMO weird:

```
obj collect { case true => true }
```

Comment: Instead of `exists { _ == true }` it is more sensible to write `exists(identity)` or `contains(true)`. Comparing bool to true is frowned upon by many programmers [Is it bad to explicitly compare against boolean constants e.g. if (b == false) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i).