# How to cover maximum number of nodes via given path in a graph?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to find out the maximum number of covered nodes via a path in a given graph. I have made a program using recursion but it is giving answer only for some simple graph not on complicated graph.

Input is given in a string array like 1#2: means node 1 is connected to node 2 or vice-versa.

I have made a matrix of total nodes size and if node is connected set 1 else -1 in matrix. This matrix is used to calculate maximum covered node in path.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 

public class Medium 
{ 
 public static int node_covered;
 public static int big=0;
 public static boolean[] visited;
 public static int matrix_length;
 public static String[][] matrix;

 public static String[] input=new String[]
 //answer is 7.
{"1#2", "2#3","3#4","3#5","5#6","5#7","6#7","7#8"};

public static void main(String[] args){
      int total_nodes=maxno_city(input);
      System.out.println(total_nodes);
  }

public static int maxno_city(String[] input1)
{
int ln=input1.length;
HashSet hs = new HashSet();

for(int i=0; i<ln;i++)
{
    String[] temp=input1[i].split("#");     
    hs.add(temp[0]);        
    hs.add(temp[1]);    
}

matrix_length=hs.size();
hs.clear();
matrix=new String[matrix_length][matrix_length];
//initialize matrix
for (String[] row : matrix)
     Arrays.fill(row, "-1");

//System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));

for(int i=0;i<matrix_length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<matrix_length;j++)
    {
        String[] temp=input1[i].split("#");
        int first=Integer.parseInt(temp[0])-1;
        int second=Integer.parseInt(temp[1])-1;
        matrix[first][second]="1";
        matrix[second][first]="1";
    }
}
//System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
//initialized
//now start work on matrix
for(int i=0;i<matrix_length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<matrix_length;j++)
    {
        visited=new boolean[matrix_length];
        if(matrix[i][j].equals("1"))
        {
            node_covered=0;
            getNextPath(j,i);
            //visited[i]=true;
        }   
    }
}
    return big;
}

//recursive method
public static void getNextPath(int path,int visited_node)
{
    boolean flag=false;
    visited[visited_node]=true;
    node_covered++;
    for(int i=0;i<matrix_length;i++)
    {
        if(matrix[path][i].equals("1") && visited[i]==false)
        {
            //visited[i]=true;
            flag=true;
            getNextPath(i,path);
            //visited[i]=false;
        }
    }
    if(flag==false)
    {
        if(big<node_covered)
        {
            big=node_covered;
            //System.out.println(big);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        node_covered--;
    }
    //visited[path]=false;
 }
}
```

Where I am doing mistake in above code?

Comment: this might be np-complete, not sure have to check

Comment: It has solution...I am skipping something. That's why I asked here.

Comment: It would be better if you pointed to the problem source so that we would have some test cases as well.

Comment: I have added three string array as a comment so you can compile and check it easily.

Comment: @NikosM. indeed, this is the [Longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-hard. I'm not sure this will be solvable for 1000 cities in reasonable time.

Comment: @MdMohsin you may improve readability and efficiency by converting `matrix` to a `boolean` matrix. Also `!visited[i]` is [often considered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i) more readable than `… == false`.

Comment: This problem *is* NP-hard. It is tractable, though, if the graph is a DAG.

Comment: @DidierL yes you are right and I will convert matrix into boolean..and thanks good info.

Comment: @JuanLopes not the case here though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your main issue** is that you do not store the complete matrix. This loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<matrix_length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<matrix_length;j++)
    {
        String[] temp=input1[i].split("#");
        int first=Integer.parseInt(temp[0])-1;
        int second=Integer.parseInt(temp[1])-1;
        matrix[first][second]="1";
        matrix[second][first]="1";
    }
}
```

does not correctly iterate over `input1` to populate `matrix`. By consequent, the last inputs are ignored (you can also see that `j` is not used at all within the inner loop). You should thus change it to a correct iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++)
{
    String[] temp = input1[i].split("#");
    int first = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]) - 1;
    int second = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]) - 1;
    matrix[first][second] = "1";
    matrix[second][first] = "1";
}
```

(You may also want to improve it further to a *foreach* loop since you don't need the value of `i`)

I discovered this by debugging your code and figuring out that it does not recurse into some nodes, and then I figured that `matrix` was incomplete. You should print `matrix` to check whether it is correct.

**Some other issues:**

- You must reset your `visited` array when backtracking, otherwise you will not evaluate 2 different paths that go through the same node (uncomment `visited[path]=false;`)
- You do not need the `flag`: in both cases, you should check if you have a new "high score" and decrease `node_covered` before leaving the loop
- Your code will fail if there is a city that is not connected to the rest of the graph, because your `Set hs` will be too small. Try to look for the node with the highest number instead.

**Some possible improvements:**

- Convert `matrix` to a `boolean` matrix. This will also remove the need to initialize it.
- You do not need 2 parameters for `getNextPath()`. Try to do everything you need with `visited_node` at the calling place. You should then be able to simplify it further.
- If you manage to reduce it to 1 parameter, you will not need 2 nested `for` loops to initiate the recursion.

Comment: Thanks for giving me valuable info and I am trying to correct code as you shared info here. Very helpful info.