# Java change array data isn't shown in output

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to change certain index values of this boolean array to false and it does change but when re-displayed in another method it doesn't print properly.

This is for an assignment at school. I've check memory locations and they are the same.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Lab11avst
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 100;
        boolean primes[];
        primes = new boolean[MAX];
        computePrimes(primes);
        displayPrimes(primes);
    }

    public static void computePrimes(boolean list[])
    {
        Arrays.fill(list, true);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length ; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] = true)
            {
                for (int j = (i+1); j < 20; j+=(i+1))
                {
                    list[j] = false;
                    System.out.println( j+" "+list[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void displayPrimes( boolean x[])
    {
        for(int y = 1; y< (x.length); y+=1)
        {
            if(x[y] =true)
            {
                System.out.print(y+ " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrong duplicate. You're doing `if (foo = true)` which assigns true to foo

Comment: You don't need to compare booleans anyway. `if(x[y])` is the same thing as `if(x[y] == true)`. Comparisons produce booleans, but you already have a boolean.

Comment: Another relevant question you might want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your `displayPrimes` and `computePrimes` methods. You have an if statement in both, `if(x[y] =true)` and `if (list[i] = true)` respectively. The operator used for comparison is two equals signs, or `==`. A single equal sign is an assignment operator that returns the new value of `x[y]` or `list[i]`. Think of `=` as a function that receives two parameters and returns the second parameter with the first parameter modified. Since `x[y]` and `list[i]`is modified to true, it will always pass your if statement check. To fix this, replace `if(x[y] =true)` with `if(x[y])` and `if (list[i] = true)` with `if (list[i])`.