# No exception in Async method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception

It appears I cannot throw exception in async methods:

```
void Start ()
{
    ReadAndThrow(null);
}

public static async Task ReadAndThrow(string path)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == true) 
    { 
         Debug.Log("Wrong"); 
         throw new Exception("Wrong"); 
    }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null) { }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I can see the debug but the exception does not print in the console. It does stop the application, basically, the exception happens but is not printed in the console.

I can use a try catch and print the error, but why is the exception omitted from console? It does not show in the error section, I checked I would miss it from there.

How could I get the exception to print?

EDIT:

Latest used code, not printing:

```
async Task Start()
{
    await ReadAndThrow(null);
}
async Task ReadAndThrow(string path)
{
    Debug.Log("Start");
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == true) { Debug.Log("Wrong"); throw new Exception("Wrong in"); }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Method" + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line = null;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to await `ReadAndThrow`?

Comment: Converted Start to async Task, added await to ReadAndThrow and still nothing.

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == true` waht?  [Don't compare to literal boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661110/is-it-bad-to-explicitly-compare-against-boolean-constants-e-g-if-b-false-i).

Comment: Could you show us that code? Did you try putting a `try catch` inside `Start`?

Comment: Try/catch in start won't do, try/catch in method will get the exception and print a debug message. Throw in catch will not do.

Comment: @Everts, try my answer below, becuase its give me an exception.

Comment: You keep describing the results **without showing the code**. Every time you try something, copy and paste the code into a new dotnetfiddle, so we can see the code you are trying.

Comment: @Everts, it give me an exception `System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'` and in that inner exception is `Wrong`

Comment: I'm thinking it could be a setting in the debug of VS since others are getting it.

Comment: Back to this, as mentioned on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eKi6NKri6I at 9:20, exception can be hidden. I guess that's what I had. Special thanks to whoever downvoted my question, probably thinking I misused the feature while it was a Unity limitation.

Answer (score 3):

`ReadAndThrow` will finish before the exception is printed. Need to `awai`t it.

Comment: I placed a "Done" debug after the method in Start and it shows that the "Wrong" debug is first printed then the "Done" but the exception is missing.

Comment: Minor typo may someone move the back tick so we have `await` instead of `awai`t

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` your method by modifying the signature of `Start()` method

```
async Task Start()
{
    await ReadAndThrow(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixes need to make to get it work. The magic is you need to wait until ReadAndThrow will be finished. Also I recommend to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

```
public Task StartAsync ()
{
    return ReadAndThrow(null); //and await StartAsync method
    //or
    await ReadAndThrow(); // do not forget to make method async 
}
```