# Using a scanner on linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, java.util.scanner

I have a task in my class which is to use a linked list and a method returning a boolean saying either true or false. The method is supposed to check if the list is sorted or not (sorted being in chronological order ex. 1, 2, 7, 14).

When I run this program I do not get any answer whether or not my list is sorted. Am I using the scanner wrong or what's going on?

```java
package Kap18;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lista {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean sorted;
        
        System.out.println("Write a few numbers");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        LinkedList<Integer> tab = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        
        while (sc.hasNextInt())
            tab.add(sc.nextInt());
        
        isSorted(tab);
        if (sorted = false){
            System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
        }
        else if (sorted = true){
            System.out.println("The list is sorted");
        }
        }
        
    public static boolean isSorted(LinkedList tab){
        boolean sorted = true;
        int i = 0;
        int num1 = (Integer)tab.get(i);
        int num2;
        for(i = 1; i <= tab.size() - 1; i++){
            num2 = (Integer)tab.get(i);
            if(num1 < num2){
                num1 = num2;
            }
            else{
                i = tab.size();
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting sorted equal to true/false in the if checks of your main method. `=` sets values, `==` checks equality. Since sorted is a boolean, you don't technically need to use `==` either. `if(sorted) { /* print is sorted */ } else { /* print not sorted */}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `sorted = false` is **assigning** `false` to `sorted`, and then using `false` for the test.  So the test is always going to say that the list is sorted.

You should use `==` rather than `=`.

However, many people (including myself) think that `variable == true` and `variable == false` is Bad Style; e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2661150/139985.  And the reasoning is that using `==` leaves open the possibility of the one character typo *that just bit you*; i.e. mistyping `==` as `=`.

(It is also redundant to use `==` and `!=` in boolean expressions *in most cases*.  But not all.)

So, I would say that the *best* way to write that is:

```
    if (!sorted) {
        System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The list is sorted");
    }
```

or maybe the other way around so that you don't need to negate the `sorted` variable.

---

A second problem is that `sorted` is not set in the first place, since you don't assign the result of the `isSorted` call to anything.

Normally you would get a compilation error for using `sorted` before it is assigned.  But in this case, the `if` statement is assigning a value to `sorted` ... due to the previous mistake.

---

Finally, there is a bug in `isSorted` in the case where the list is empty.  (Try it and see ...)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First, you ignore the return value of `isSorted`. Second, you  assign `false` and then `true` to the `sorted` variable in the `if` statements by using the `=` operator instead of `==`. In the case of booleans, the easiest way to avoid such mistakes is to check the variable directly instead of comparing it to `true` or `false`:

```
sorted = isSorted(tab);
if (sorted) {
    System.out.println("The list is sorted");
}
else if (sorted = true){
    System.out.println("The list is not sorted");        
}
```