# Basic boolean logic in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean

Which is better of the following?

```
this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"] == true;
```

or

```
this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];
```

It needs be to true ONLY when the session is true. If the session is set to false will this evaluate to true in #2 as it exists? Or is it evaluating its value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusing If Statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407617/confusing-if-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one:

```
this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];
```

`(bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"]` is already a boolean (so will be either `true` or `false`), so no need for the extra comparison and return value of the boolean expression.

Either way, you need to check that the `li` session variable exists before trying to cast it, or your code will throw (I think a `NullReferenceException`).

Answer (score 2):

The latter is clearer, IMO. They're functionally equivalent though - in both cases, it will fetch the value of "li" from the session and attempt to cast it to `bool`, throwing an exception if the value isn't present.

Comment: Thanks, so they are both just evaluating the values of the session, and not evaluating if the session variable exists or not?  (Like Javascript)

Comment: @Tom: Yes - the expression `(bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];` is going to be evaluated either way.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Is it so, i thought a boolean would become false if it is `null`?

Comment: @Tim: Nope, you're trying to perform an unboxing conversion, and that's going to fail if you don't unbox a genuine `bool`.

Comment: @Jon: But why does `Dim b As Boolean = Nothing` evaluates to `false`(option strict) in VB.Net and does not throw an exception?

Comment: @Tim: Because Nothing in VB isn't quite the same as null in C#. In some contexts it's equivalent to default(T) instead.

Comment: @Jon: thanks for claifying. Sometimes VB.Net frightens me. It makes no sense at first sight why this throws an exception: `DirectCast(obj, Boolean)`(if obj is an object that is nothing) and this is `false`: `DirectCast(nothing , Boolean)`.

Comment: @Tim, when dealing with this, it's better to use nullable variable, DirectCast(obj, Boolean?) or DirectCast(obj, nullable(of Boolean))

Answer (score 1):

Create a property for the desired value:

```
public bool IsLoggedIn {
  get { return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"]; }
}
```

You could even go one extra level, if the session is used a lot in the class:

```
public bool IsLoggedIn {
  get { return (bool)Session["li"]; }
}

private HttpSessionState Session {
  get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
}
```

Also, if you ever want to look at the session by itself, use a better key, like `"IsLoggedIn"`, instead of `"li"`.

It might be good to create a special class for these application-wide values:

```
public static class MyAppSession {

  const string IsLoggedInKey = "IsLoggedIn";

  public static bool IsLoggedIn {
    get { 
      return Session[IsLoggedInKey] != null && (bool)Session[IsLoggedInKey]; 
    }
    internal set { Session[IsLoggedInKey] = value; }
  }

  // ...

  private static HttpSessionState Session {
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second approach is equivalent, but the first one is to verbose for my taste. I like the second one much better.

Just as I like this

```
bool accepted = true;
if( accepted)
{
  ..
}
```

Better than

```
bool accepted = true;
if( accepted == true)
{
  ..
}
```

I feel it clearer that way if the variables are properly named.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the expected value in the place of the expression, and it will become pretty clear:

```
First example:
Before: this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"] == true;
After:  this.isLoggedIn = true == true;

Second example:
Before: this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];
After:  this.isLoggedIn = true;
```

Now, try the same for the `false` case:

```
First example:
Before: this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"] == true;
After:  this.isLoggedIn = false == true;

Second example:
Before: this.isLoggedIn = (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];
After:  this.isLoggedIn = false;
```

As you can see, there will be no difference in the result between the two approaches. It all comes down to questions about coding style and readability, where I would guess that you would find a bias towards the shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to write code that says:

bool x = (y == true);

Instead just use

```
bool x = y;
```

In your specific case you should use:

```
this.isLoggedIn = HttpContext.Current.Session["li"] != null 
    && (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["li"];
```

This way you will not get an exception if Session["li"] has not been assigned yet.  However you will get an exception if Session["li"] is not castable to bool.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second option with a variant:
this.isLoggedIn = (bool) (HttpContext.Current.Session["li"] ?? "false");

The ?? is [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) - it gives a value of "false" to the expression on its lefthand side, in case it happens to be null.

Answer (score -1):

Both pieces of code are equal, so the better is the second (it's shorter).

Comment: @Ishtar, Do you think that `== true` is really necessary?

Comment: Certainly not. But it looks like you say shorter==better, hence the code golf. (Didn't downvote btw)

Comment: @Ishtar, I like 256-byte intros :)