# VB.NET: Boolean from `Nothing` sometimes `false`, sometimes Nullreference-Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, compiler-construction, casting

Coming from *[Basic boolean logic in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803557/c-basic-boolean-logic-question/4803572#4803572)*, I was wondering why:

```
Dim b As Boolean
Dim obj As Object = Nothing
'followig evaluates to False'
b = DirectCast(Nothing, Boolean)
'This throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"-Exception'
b = DirectCast(obj, Boolean)
```

A `CType(obj, Boolean)` would evaluate to `False`(just as `CBool(obj))`. I think it is because the compiler uses a helper function, but that is not my theme.

Why does casting `Nothing` to `Boolean` evaluates to `False`, whereas casting an object that is `Nothing` to `Boolean` throws an Nullreference-Exception? Does that make sense?

```
[Option Strict ON]
```

Comment: some answer in here refer to framework 2.0, this is about 3.5. there is nullable type in 3.5 for VB

Comment: @Fredou: The answer to this question isn't dependent on a particular version of the Framework, and nullable types are not the solution. The asker isn't looking for a *solution*, but rather than *explanation* why the code behaves as it does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presumably, this is because [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) in VB.NET is not exactly the same thing as `null` in C#.

In the case of value types, `Nothing` implies the *default value* of that type. In the case of a `Boolean`, the default value is `False`, so the cast succeeds.

> One of the primary differences between value types such as Integer or structures and reference types such as Form or String is that reference types support a null value. That is to say, a reference type variable can contain the value Nothing, which means that the variable doesn't actually refer to a value. In contrast, a value type variable always contains a value. An Integer variable always contains a number, even if that number is zero. If you assign the value Nothing to a value type variable, the value type variable just gets assigned its default value (in the case of Integer, that default value is zero). There is no way in the current CLR to look at an Integer variable and determine whether it has never been assigned a value - the fact that it contains zero doesn't necessarily mean that it hasn't been assigned a value.
>   
>     –[The Truth about Nullable Types and VB...](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2004/06/04/1180.aspx)

**EDIT**: For further clarification, the reason the second example throws a `NullReferenceException` at run-time is because the CLR is attempting to unbox the `Object` (a reference type) to a `Boolean`. This fails, of course, because the object was initialized with a null reference (setting it equal to `Nothing`):

```
Dim obj As Object = Nothing
```

Remember that, as I explained above, the VB.NET keyword `Nothing` still works the same way as `null` in C# when it comes to *reference types*. That explains why you're getting a `NullReferenceException` because the object you're attempting to cast is literally a null reference. It does not contain a value at all, and therefore cannot be unboxed to a `Boolean` type.

You don't see the same behavior when you try to cast the keyword `Nothing` to a Boolean, i.e.:

```
Dim b As Boolean = DirectCast(Nothing, Boolean)
```

because the keyword `Nothing` (this time, in the case of *value types*) simply means "the default value of this type". In the case of a `Boolean`, that's `False`, so the cast is logical and straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. But it is still not pointed out why an Nullreference-Exception will be thrown on runtime, if i try to cast an object that is nothing to a boolean. It could also be casted to false because the default value for boolean is false.

Comment: @Tim: No, it couldn't. At least, not necessarily. Remember that an `Object` is a *reference type*, not a value type. As I explained, the `Nothing` keyword still works the same way as `null` in C# when it comes to reference types. When you set a variable of type `Object` to `Nothing`, that means it does not contain a value.

Comment: @Cody gray: That means the CLR is looking whether the object is a value type or a reference type. If the latter it directly throws a NullReferenceException if it should do something with it(f.e. casting). If i try to cast `Nothing` to a Boolean the compiler implicitly assignes `False` to it, hence the CLR will not throw an exception because the casting is not done on runtime but on compile-time. Correct?

Comment: this quote (The Truth about Nullable Types and VB) is for framework 2.0, this question is about 3.5, so use nullable variable aka Dim b as boolean? or dim b as nullable(of boolean)

Comment: @Fredou: i didn't want to know if it's possible to cast a null-reference object to a boolean without a Nullreference-Exception, but to know what's going on behind the scenes(compiler,CLR).

Comment: @Tim: Yes, the CLR is attempting to *unbox* the `Object` (a reference type) to a `Boolean`. This fails, of course, because you've assigned a null reference (which is what `Nothing` means for reference types). That's why you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, because the object is literally a null reference. You don't see the same behavior when you try to cast the keyword `Nothing` to a `Boolean` because the keyword `Nothing` (in the case of reference types) simply means "the default value of this type". In the case of a `Boolean`, that's `False`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes it does. If you would add this comment to your answer i would accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: Excellent. I've updated my answer, although I think the comments make a little bit more sense when read in context. @downvoter: What part of my answer do you disagree with? If you think there's a correction that I need to make, I'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of things you have to realize here.

The *first* is what others have already pointed out: `Nothing` *can* be interpreted by the VB compiler as simply the `Boolean` value `False` given the proper context, such as `Dim b As Boolean = Nothing`.

This means that when the compiler sees this:

```
b = DirectCast(Nothing, Boolean)
```

It sees a literal (`Nothing`) and also sees that you want to use this literal as a `Boolean`. That makes it a no-brainer.

But now here's the *second* thing you have to realize. `DirectCast` on an `Object` is essentially an unboxing operation (for value types). So what **needs** to happen from the VB compiler's perspective is: there *needs* to be a `Boolean` in that box, or else the operation will fail. Since there is in fact *nothing* in the box—and this time we're really talking *nothing*, as in `null`—it throws an exception.

If I were to translate this code to C#, it would look like this:

```
bool b;
object obj = null;

b = (bool)default(bool);

b = (bool)obj;
```

Hopefully that makes things a bit clearer?

Comment: +1 Although a minor quibble. I'm not sure about the wording of "we're really talking `Nothing`" when (I think) you mean a reference variable containing `Nothing` rather than the literal `Nothing`. Surely the literal `Nothing` is as real as it gets? Anyway, this is a better answer than mine was...

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between using the **keyword** (literal) `Nothing`, and using a reference **variable** whose value is `Nothing`.

- In VB.NET, the literal (keyword) [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx) gets special treatment. The `Nothing` **keyword** can be automatically converted into a value type, using the default value of that type.
- A reference **variable** whose value is `Nothing` is different. You don't get the special behaviour.
- The documentation says [DirectCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) "requires an inheritance or implementation relationship between the data types of the two arguments".
- Clearly `Object` does not inherit from or implement `Boolean`, unless you have put a boxed `Boolean` into an object variable.

So the code below fails at runtime with an exception.

```
 Dim obj As Object = Nothing  
 b = DirectCast(obj, Boolean)
```

Comment: As i have mentioned at the end of my question, i have `Option Strict` but it fails on runtime.  Have a look at my last comment on Cody Gray's answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This answer it totally right except for that last part, which, as Tim notes, is not related to the problem. (`Option Strict` is not going to prevent you from downcasting an `Object` to a `Boolean`; that always *could* work assuming it's a boxed `Boolean`!)

Comment: @Tim @Dan Oops, thanks, I will delete that last bit. Oh and +1 to Dan's answer too.

Comment: @Tim Also, +1 to the question. Made me think anyway!

Comment: It may sometimes be helpful to think it terms of there being "parallel universes" of storage location types and heap-object types; defining a value type will actually a separate type in each universe (the official CIL documentation doesn't use the term "parallel universe", but does refer to the existence of separate types).  The two types mostly behave similarly, but not identically; special rules come into play when crossing between the two universes.  Casting `Object` to `Boolean` requires going between universes, while casting `Nothing` to `Boolean` does not.

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected behavior, you need this code:

```
Dim b As Boolean?
Dim obj As Object = Nothing  
b = DirectCast(obj, Boolean?)
```

The character `?` mean `Nullable(of )`.

Comment: It would be the expected behaviour if i would get an InvalidCast-Exception on compiletime. It was also more an theoretical question why the vb.net compiler behaves different to the C#. Thanks for the hint, i will change to VS 2010 next week, then i'm able to use this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding that comparing of the Boolean variable to a string of "True", "False" or Is nothing seems to ensure that I get the correct comparisons.  I was using a function to return an html string of a div with an image of a checked or unchecked radio button and was having the issue of nothing coming back as false.  Using the variable = "True" or "False" string and doing the last check with IS NOTHING helped to resolve that issue.

```
Dim b as boolean = nothing

response.write CheckValue(b = "True")
response.write (b = "False")
response.write (b is nothing)

Function CheckValue(inVal as boolean) as string
  if inVal then 
    return ("<div><img src="checked.png" ></div>
  else
    return ("<div><img src="unchecked.png" ></div>    
  end if
end function
```

The system seems to do the conversion to string when implicitly compared to a string whereas using the ***.tostring*** method just creates an error while allowing the last comparison to actually compare to a value of ***nothing***.

Hopefully that helps somewhat.  It at least let me

Comment: `isNothing(b)` in a condition statement will indeed work as a by-pass to the `Nothing`. The answer above is correct but I'm glad someone found a way around it, hence the upvote.